# computercraft/lua program looping unable to maintain signal output

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm trying to write a program that gets the time from the os.time() function and use that to change a redstone output. When rebooting, the program is set to auto-run, but since I reboot to cause the program to restart, it interrupts then starts the code again. I have already tried loops in several places and forms to update the time variable without rebooting, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. (I'm still open to a solution with loops if it will work)

Code:

```
shell.run("time") 
x = os.time()
print(x)
if x > 18.500 then
  redstone.setOutput("left", true)
elseif x < 6.500 then
  redstone.setOutput("left",true)
else redstone.setOutput("left",false)
end
sleep(2)
os.reboot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldnt need the os.reboot(), your code should simply look like this:

```
while true
shell.run("time") 
x = os.time()
print(x)
if x > 18.500 then
  redstone.setOutput("left", true)
elseif x < 6.500 then
  redstone.setOutput("left",true)
else redstone.setOutput("left",false)
end
sleep(2)
end
```

Comment: Anyone wanting a lighting system based off in-game time, here's a viable solution using a computer from ComputerCraft